# Why pagination does not work? And how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a request to a local server. And server returns to me the follow response:

```
{"total":7,
"perPage":3,
"page":1,
"lastPage":3,
 "data":[
     {"id":1,"title":"animals","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."},
     {"id":2,"title":"space","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."},
     {"id":3,"title":"sport","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."}
]}
```

- **data** - it list of categories. And I display my list in the form of a table.
- **total, perPage, page, lastPage** - it query param which I will insert into URL to filter my list.
- **page** - the current page number. If in field page would be number two, then it would be in data the other three objects. That is, there would be in data other categories, with other `title` and `id`.

I have a task:

- make pagination with three buttons. Because I have three pages `"lastPage":3`.And how I implemented it (I comment some line):

file **Home.js**:

```js
const Home = () => {

     const [value, setValue] = useState({
         listCategory: [],                   //  here I put my list of categories
         currentPage: 1                      // here I set initial page
     });

      useEffect(() => {
         fetchData();
      },[]);

      async function fetchData() {
         try {
            const res = await apiCategory('api/categories', { //apiCategory it function I'll write it below    
              method:'GET'
            });
              console.log(res);
              setValue({
                  listCategory:res.data,       // I put the received data in an empty array to display the category list on the page
                  currentPage:res.page          // set page which is default in response from server, now it-("page":1)
              });
            } catch(e) { 
                console.error(e);
            } 
    };

     const changePage = (argPage) => {
         setValue({
             currentPage: argPage               // change page depending on which button was pressed
         });
     }

      return (
        <div>
            <Search/>
            <Table dataAttribute = {value.listCategory} />    // dispaly category list

            {Object.keys(value.currentPage).map((item, index) => (
               <button key={item} onClick={() => changePage(index)}>{item}</button>
            ))}         // dispaly button and attach method changePage

        </div>
    )}
```

There is function `apiCategory`:

```js
export const apiCategory = async (url, args) => { 
const getToken = localStorage.getItem('myToken');
const valuePage = value.currentPage;               //currentPage- props of my state in useState
  const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${url}?page=${valuePage}`, {  //I substitute in URL value from valuePage that implement pagination
   ...args,
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8 ",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${getToken}`,
      "Accept": 'application/json',
      ...args.headers,  
    },
  });

 return response.json();      
}
```

But I did not have buttons that switch pages (pagination). Only category list displays(screenshot):
https://i.piccy.info/i9/0b04d1777b6769e3a4dcb500faa3554a/1587741736/24398/1372209/Screenshot_1.png

Maybe even they do not change their condition. I don't know...

Also in function `apiCategory` I have an error:

> **'value' is not defined  no-undef**

in this line:
`const valuePage = value.currentPage;`

What should I change in the code so that buttons appear and pagination works?

I will also write a file **Table.js**:

```js
export default ({dataAttribute}) => (
  <table className="table">
    <thead className="table-head">
      <tr >
        <th>id</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>created_at</th>
        <th>updated_at</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.id}</td>
          <td>{item.title}</td>
          <td>{item.created_at}</td>
          <td>{item.updated_at}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `value` into the `apiCategory` function, otherwise it is undefined. If you want `fetchData` to fire every time the next page is selected then it needs to be a dependency in `useEffect`.

**Home.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData(currentPage) {
    try {
      const res = await apiCategory('api/categories', {
        method:'GET'
      }, currentPage);
      console.log(res);
      setValue({
        listCategory:res.data
        currentPage:res.page
      });
    } catch(e) { 
      console.error(e);
    } 
  };
  fetchData(value.currentPage);
},[value.currentPage]);
```

**apCategory.js**

```
export const apiCategory = async (url, args, valuePage) => { 
...
// remove the local valuePage line
```

Also note that you are removing the `listCategory` property in `value` every time `changePage` is called. To preseve the previous values, you need to change it to this:

```
const changePage = (argPage) => {
   setValue((prev) => {
     return {
       ...prev,
       currentPage: argPage 
     }
   });
 }
```

In your return you aren't referring to the data structure properly.

```
{
    // iterate through each element in `value.ListCategory`
    value.listCategory.map((item, index) => (
      <button 
        key={'listCategory_'+item.id} 
        onClick={() => changePage(index + 1)}
      >
        {index + 1}
      </button>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Then I have error:
http://piccy.info/view3/13772171/fb4bb7a3ae2fb7ffaa486d86f6f6abf0/

Comment: And how to pass value into the apiCategory function? What change in file apiCategory.js and Home.js?

Comment: @john I edited the answer for more clarity and fixed the typo

Comment: I did so, the list is there, but there are no buttons( Maybe I display my screen in meeting in Zoom? Do you have Zoom?

Comment: if I'm here in curentPage:
```const [value, setValue] = useState({
         listCategory: [],
         currentPage: 1
     });```
manually change number that my list change, but not button in page. User cannot change code, he need button

Comment: @john I added a section with the problem of your return

Comment: new error:https://i.piccy.info/i9/7b2e288d6d157fb97a21253b4cfe8ebf/1587748752/16821/1372209/new_error.png
and all code with your changes:http://i.piccy.info/i9/8b2121bb3772331bf093cc80a224cf4f/1587748837/106609/1372209/all2.png

Comment: finally made a normal comment, please see my last comment

Comment: @john I fixed it, you should be able to debug these small sort of things by yourself

Comment: see look what appeared with buttons:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/c2293cf72bd1ab12ed04573881e3140d/1587749376/65140/1372209/Screenshot_3.png
Must be only buttons( Sorry that I  bother you, but please help me finish it. I'm just new to programming

Comment: @biwlit Also button 0 does nothing, but the 3 button does not exist at all

Comment: Ok I made the final edit. You cannot expect people to do everything for you here especially when it is not clear what your goal is or why you tried the things you have tried.

Comment: http://i.piccy.info/i9/bb4b299b82a00530f654409cb0e6d1b4/1587750077/21678/1372209/Screenshot_4.png
Now it’s almost good, but I need 1,2,3 buttons, the 0 button does nothing

Comment: I know already tortured you, but already so close to the finish.Your help is very much needed

Comment: I made the edit to use the `id` instead of the map `index`

Comment: And now when I press button 2 my button change to this:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/34883037def53ee9ed1b7a7a50438900/1587751905/20167/1372209/Screenshot_8.png
when I press button 3 my button change to this:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/1d43382904456032c752317ef5b7c965/1587751813/13259/1372209/Screenshot_7.png

Comment: I did not insert the correct screenshot look at my last comment again